# Which pygame modules have an init attribute? I would like to manually initialize modules rather than using pygame.init()

Tags: pygame

For example:

1. pygame.display.init() works because pygame.display has an init attribute
2. pygame.event.init() does NOT work because pygame.event does NOT have init attribute

Or is there a way to generate the list of modules when pygame.init() is run?

"You can always initialize individual modules manually, but pygame.init() is a convenient way to get everything started." (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html)

Comment: You can just look through the docs and check which modules have an `init` attribute. Why do you expect us to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way through which you can check how many modules are initialized

```py
import pygame 
(item1,item2) = pygame.init() 
print('Number of modules initialized :', item1)
#There are 6 in total
```

I do know 4 pygame modules which have a `.init()` function

```py
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.fastevent.init() #This is required for event response
```